# Parallel Execution with respect to input in Protractor

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, gulp-protractor

Having Login Page details(username,password and login button) in single spec.js file

Wanted to login spec file with valid and invalid credentials which are already mentioned in input.json file but parallely using protractor

Expected O/P: Browser 1 is try to login with valid and Browser 2 try to login with invalid credentials

How to perform such parallel execution actions using protractor?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to different browsers, but probably using multicapabilities, can achieve this. Define specs with valid and invalid tests.

```
    multiCapabilities: [{
    'name': 'test1',
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    specs: ['login_valid_test.js'],
  }, {
    'name': 'test2',
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    specs: ['login_invalid_test.js'],
  }]
```